# How do I display error text via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, text, validation, validating

I'm validating forms with Javascript, and I found out how to switch borders/backgrounds of input fields if there is an error, but I want to display text next to the box.  How would I do that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a div object next to the respective box, give it a certain width in its style attribute to make it visible, and then find it in javascript by using the DOM or just getElementById(...), and modify its innerHTML by using js. (as in, myDiv.innerHTML = ...).

Comment: This is indeed the most simple way.. it's also possible to create the div on the fly and place it near the textbox. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the jQuery Validate plugin this could be handled for you. Here's an example http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Example (just push the Submit button).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?

If you you can use something like this:

```
jQueryElement.addClass('error').after('<span class="errorMessage">error message here</span>');
```